# How do I add "marginal" labels to bibliography entries in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, bibliography

I'm currently in the process of finalizing my research for the City Council of Rochester: Police Accountability Board. Of course (when conducting research), one must provide citations/bibliography entries to substantiate any claim that's made.

Nevertheless, I'm primarily concerned with the format of my bibliography; I want to add labels to each bibliography entry, as seen here on page 2  https://roccitylibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/Rochester-African-American-History-Final.pdf, where each entry is preceded with its corresponding call-number. How do I do this in Microsoft Word?

I've tried using the **Table** format, **Bullet** format, indenting,  altering the **Paragraph** format etc-- all was of no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a Paragraph Style with a marginal Frame.

The way I would do this would be to use Frames to insert the marginal entries in the Bibliography in the Final Copy. *Word does not have an automatic method of doing this.* If you have to update the bibliography after you add these, they will be lost. If you need to do that, I would recommend saving a copy and then copying and pasting the old entries into the updated copy and doing further manual updating.

Here is [Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on using Frames for Marginal Text](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/MarginalText.htm#TrueMarginalText). Here is [my page on Frames and Textboxes](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#sidebars).

The basic idea is to create a custom paragraph style that includes frame formatting and use that style for your marginal text. I have styles for both the left and right margins on my system. Note, though, that these do not switch if the location of the basic bibliography entry moves from a left column to a right column.

Frames can be created using the Format > Frame commands on the Style definition. They can also be created using the legacy command on the Developer Tab as discussed in the linked pages.

*By the way, your sample was almost certainly set up using Tables. Here is [my page on Tables](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm).*